# How to run a bash script with a systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I want to start a graphical application via systemd. I tried to do that via udev before, but the application is killed after the rule terminates. It works when I run the application directly via systemd, but not when I run the script that starts the application with some constraints.

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=App starter

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=HOME=/home/user/
ExecStart=/home/user/runApp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

journalctl -xe gives me

```
Sep 25 13:50:00 host systemd[1]: Starting App starter...
Subject: A start job for unit app.service has begun execution
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
A start job for unit xournalpp.service has begun execution.
 
The job identifier is 19196.
Sep 25 13:50:00 host runApp[313232]: App is not running
Sep 25 13:50:00 host systemd[1]: app.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
An ExecStart= process belonging to unit xournalpp.service has exited.
 
The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Sep 25 13:50:00 host systemd[1]: app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
The unit xournalpp.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 25 13:50:00 host systemd[1]: Failed to start App starter.
Subject: A start job for unit app.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
 
A start job for unit app.service has finished with a failure.
 
The job identifier is 19196 and the job result is failed.
```

Here is the script. Might it be due to the running in background by `&`? In need this because I want to reuse the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

  if pgrep app
  then
      echo App is running
          wmctrl -x -a app
          wmctrl -x -r app -b "add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
          
  else
          echo App is not running
          /usr/bin/app & disown
  fi
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the script? What if the content is very simple (e.g. `echo 1`) - it might just be a problem with e.g. loading the environment in the script. You are also defining `DISPLAY`, thus maybe `graphical.target` instead of `multi-user.target` seems more fitting. Last but not least it looks like the user should run it on login, I guess? Please specify.

Comment: The ``&`` was the problem apparently. I think this is also not the right way to do what I want to do, since the unit keeps on running.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a permission problem.

`/home/user` usually does not allow any user other to access them and security system like apparmor and selinux usualy forbidden such usage.

If you want to use a script in systemd, you'd better put it in `/usr/local/bin`.